# xsl number()-function cannot convert

Tags: xslt, apache-fop

I am using fop 1.0 in a .NET application.
My stylesheet looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet ... version="1.0" ...>
...
<xsl:param name="fromPerson" select="'1'"/>
<xsl:param name="toPerson" select="'1'"/>
...
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Person']">
   <xsl:if test="(position() &gt;= number($fromPerson))>
   ...
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is that the function number() fails with:

```
Zeilennummer221; Spaltennummer267; #UNKNOWN (cli.System.Int32) kann nicht in eine Zahl
konvertiert werden!
(Position des Fehlers unbekannt)org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:root"
is missing child elements. Required content model: (layout-master-set, declarations?,  
bookmark-tree?, (page-sequence|fox:external-document)+) (Keine Kontextinformationen  
verf³gbar)
```

Important:

```
#UNKNOWN (cli.System.Int32) cannot be converted into an integer
```

btw: I tested it by printing out the value with <xsl:message> 

Any idea why this brings out the error?

Answer (score 1):

The types of value that can be passed to global stylesheet parameters depend on the API of the processor. I guess you are using a processor whose API does not allow values of type cli.System.Int32.

Indeed, the types accepted by the Microsoft API are listed here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addparam.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I think you need an `<xsl:variable>`, not an `<xsl:param>`. Parameters are subelements of the `<xsl:template>` element (or in XSLT 2 of an `<xsl:function>` element.

Comment: You are wrong. Param can be passed to xslt from outside if specified as a top element like here. This is possible in xslt 1.0 and 2.0.

Comment: I did not know that, and I thought the #UNKNOWN is contained in variable $fromPerson as opposed to param $fromPerson.